# How do I create an axis with dates in ILNumerics plots?

Tags: ilnumerics

I am trying to create a 2D scatter plot with DateTime values along the x-axis using ILNumerics.  From my research this can be achieved by:

- Using integer DateTime ticks (DTTs) as the DateTime position coordinate
- Writing a `LabelTransformFunc` to create the DateTime string (label expression) for the DTT value of a given axes tick

  `timeSeriesPlotCube.Axes.XAxis.Ticks.LabelTransformFunc = (ind, val) =>
  {
     var tickDateTime = new DateTime ((long)val)
     return tickDateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
  };`

The problem I have is the automatic axes scaling factor that ILNumerics applies to large/small tick values is not provided in the `val` parameter passed to the `LabelTransformFunc` and therefore I cannot directly convert the `val` parameter to a DateTime string (the `val` parameter is the DTT value divided by the scaling factor).

My question is three-fold:

1. Can the automatic axes scaling factor be switched off?
2. How can I read the value of the axes scaling factor?
3. Are there any alternative approaches to implementing such a basic chart?

I have tried various approaches to (2) including reading the text value of the `ScaleLabel`, but `timeSeriesPlotCube.Axes.XAxis.ScaleLabel.Text` is always empty.

Thanks,

Len

Comment: Why not using manual mode and giving the labels for ticks explicitly?

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have exactly the same problem.